# Error when attempting to enable second level Hibernate cache in Spring-Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, spring-orm

Below is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sharique" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:/DB.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${DriverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${JDBC.URL}" />
        <property name="username" value="${USERNAME}" />
        <property name="password" value="${PASSWORD}" />
        <!-- <property name="initialSize" value="2" /> <property name="maxActive" 
            value="5" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sharique.domainObjects" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${HIBERNATE.DIALECT}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${HBM2DDL_AUTO_UPDATE}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${SHOW_SQL_TRUE}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"></property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

In my application, hibernate is integrated with spring and everything was working fine till I tried to enable second level cache in my application. It has started giving me an exception.  Please help, how to resolve this issue.
I am using hibernate 4.3.8.Final and spring 4.1.4.RELEASE.
Below is the full stack trace of that exception.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sharique.service.ExpenseServiceManagement com.sharique.controller.ExpenseController.expenseServiceManagement; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseServiceManagementImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sharique.dao.ExpenseDao com.sharique.service.impl.ExpenseServiceManagementImpl.expenseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sharique.dao.impl.ExpenseDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MVCLayer/WEB-INF/lib/DAOLayer.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sharique.service.ExpenseServiceManagement com.sharique.controller.ExpenseController.expenseServiceManagement; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseServiceManagementImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sharique.dao.ExpenseDao com.sharique.service.impl.ExpenseServiceManagementImpl.expenseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sharique.dao.impl.ExpenseDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MVCLayer/WEB-INF/lib/DAOLayer.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseServiceManagementImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sharique.dao.ExpenseDao com.sharique.service.impl.ExpenseServiceManagementImpl.expenseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sharique.dao.impl.ExpenseDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MVCLayer/WEB-INF/lib/DAOLayer.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sharique.dao.ExpenseDao com.sharique.service.impl.ExpenseServiceManagementImpl.expenseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sharique.dao.impl.ExpenseDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MVCLayer/WEB-INF/lib/DAOLayer.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sharique.dao.impl.ExpenseDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MVCLayer/WEB-INF/lib/DAOLayer.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.sharique.dao.impl.ExpenseDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MVCLayer/WEB-INF/lib/DAOLayer.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/MVCLayer/WEB-INF/lib/DAOLayer.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache.use_second_level_cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Nested property in path 'cache.use_second_level_cache' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:919)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cache' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'cache' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:916)
    ... 63 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${HIBERNATE.DIALECT}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${HBM2DDL_AUTO_UPDATE}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${SHOW_SQL_TRUE}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"></property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate,cache.EhCacheProvider"></property>
```

you should have

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${HIBERNATE.DIALECT}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${HBM2DDL_AUTO_UPDATE}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${SHOW_SQL_TRUE}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma instead of a dot in the cache provider config:

```
<property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate,cache.EhCacheProvider"></property>
```

It should be:

```
<property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"></property>
```

Comment: Yeah...i saw that too and I corrected it..but its still the same issue.
It says there is nor such property